# How can I make the background of elements of my blog transparent in Blogger?

Tags: html, background, transparency, blogger

On on my Blog (http://www.ourunitedvoice.org/) there is a great deal of empty white space that I want to change to be transparent so my background shows off more in my blog similar to this blog: http://wholefoodsmarket.com/blog/whole-story.

I don't know what HTML needs to be changed on these various page components to remove the white and make them see through. Hoping someone can help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this to the `body` css:

```
body {
background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
```

The last "0" will make the background transparent

Answer (score -1):

Sir you are using a png file 
while the other site is using CSS

there is no magic learn some CSS and you will solve your problem